# Telephony phone state not comparing correctly?

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

When comparing `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE` with `TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` in an if statement it is saying they are different when they should be the same.

Logging the `EXTRA_STATE` and `EXTRA_STATE_RINGING` it gives me the same response that they are both "RINGING" I have also tried comparing it directly to the text "RINGING"

In OnReceive

```java
        Log.d("DebugData", intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE));
        Log.d("DebugData", TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING);
        if (intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE) == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) {
            Log.d("DebugData", "The Phone is ringing");
        } else {
            // Do Nothing
        }
```

I expect the comparison to output true but it outputs false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't compare strings in Java with `==`, you need to use `.equals()` instead.

e.g.

```
if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE))) { ... }
```

read more here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/

Comment: interesting, I never knew this. Still a beginner in java but interested.